# Create a file link in org-mode that accepts spaces in the text

Tags: org-mode, customize, hyperlinks

My org file looks something like this:

```
* Space Radiation
** Gamma Ray Info 
   - file://Library\March 2015\Gamma Ray Radiation Fundamentals.pdf
   - some notes
```

However the title has spaces so the link stops at the first space. As I have literally thousands of collected papers and books that spaces in the name, adding %20 or even '+' to fill the space is a major task and also makes the linked document title difficult to read especially if you have several lines of such links.

Is there a way to work around this without having to change all the file names to convert or delete the spaces in the file name?

Comment: What are you using to highlight the urls/make links?

Comment: Please clarify the question by describing exactly what you are doing to create the links you mention. Otherwise, the question risks being closed because it is unclear.

Comment: I stepped in to remove a bunch of irrelevant details from the question and added code markup.  Now it is at least clear why this is a question.

Answer (score 16):

If you put the links in a file using org-mode (e.g. ending in .org), you can create links like this by:

```org
[[file:d:/path/to/filename with spaces]]
```

I'm assuming you are on Windows, and this works for on Windows 8, Emacs 24.4.1.

Comment: After updating all that, Meaningful Username has the answer. It didn't initially work for me but a restart of my installation fixed that. Thanks. Org makes an amazing documentation organizer. Finding a piece of software that properly provides a text file with full path and name was a task. Regexp does the renaming.