# File link in Org mode to a file that has spaces in it’s file name on Mac

Tags: org-mode

Yes, I know this question has been asked before and [solved](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13036/create-a-file-link-in-org-mode-that-accepts-spaces-in-the-text) for Windows users but the solution does not work for me under MacOS 10.13.6 and Emacs 26.1

I have a file on my desktop named "Test with Spaces.rtf". When I drag this file into a Terminal window I get the path "/Users/RonDoe1/Desktop/Test\ with\ Spaces.rtf"

Now I write in Emacs org mode "[[file:/Users/RonDoe1/Desktop/Test\ with\ Spaces.rtf][Test]]" which collapses nicely to "Test". So far so good. But:

When I click on "Test" I get the error message in the minibuffer:

"No such file: /Users/RonDoe1/Desktop/Test\ with\ Spaces.rtf"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Take the \ out of the link.

Comment: John Kitchin, you solved my problem. Thanks a ton.